# Apache 2.4 - Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache

I've been trying to find a solution to this but with no avail.

I'm using wamp and running apache 2.4. Whenever I try to access a document located in my www/drupal/website directory I get that Forbidden error.

My **httpd.conf** file had the following configuration:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

I changed it to the below but I had no luck in making it work.

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried the below as well - same result:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have also tried to modify the **vhosts.conf**. My default settings were: (I do not know why I have that twice)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried changing the first vhost tags to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wwwRoot/file"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Vlad.

Comment: Check error_log for information, which directory your are trying to access. Looks like you have a wrong DocumentRoot.

Comment: Hi umka, thank you for the suggestion. After looking in my error log I was able to figure out what the problem was, it had nothing to do with the access level, it was indeed an issue with the DocumentRoot.